# BASH - Push file contents with 100000/more lines in an Array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, hash, hashmap

Can someone point me what I may be missing here? How can put a file (with 100/1000 or lines in an array and whether it's possible. The lines will have spaces/special characters etc.

To mimic what I need is, here's an example. At command line, I can do this to create an array and it works.

```
[userMe@fastServer goga]$ aaa=("1 my name is koba" "2 you name is shenzi")

[userMe@fastServer goga]$ echo ${aaa[0]}
1 my name is koba

[userMe@fastServer goga]$ echo ${aaa[1]}
2 your name is shenzi
```

Now, What I want is: If I put those 2 lines in a file /tmp/ks.txt i.e.

```
[userMe@fastServer goga]$ cat /tmp/ks.txt
1 my name is koba
2 you name is shenzi
```

**Then my questions are**:

1. What command can I run to populate the array? I tried this but it didn't work, it's NOT taking the full first line in [0] and full 2nd line in [1] index.

   *aaa=($(cat /tmp/ks.txt | sed "s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/")); echo ${aaa[0]} and ${arr[1]}*
2. How BASH array will work / their limit, when the file has 100000/more of lines in it.

I want to use Arrays (instead of using files) while doing **grep** command to find bunch of words in these lines. Thought using arrays will be faster than file operations. Please advise otherwise.

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) ("How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?") and [Bash FAQ 005](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream) ("Loading lines from a file or stream" into an array).

Comment: If you are trying to find *any* of the words in the array in files with grep (all at once) then using a file to store the words one-per-line and using `-Fwf wordfile` is probably the best approach.

Comment: Thanks Etan. Actually I found the missing piece. All I need to do was add an extra "|" (after I thought carefully enough) to do "tr '\012' ' '" using eval. I know eval is not that safe but it's working. BTW, I have a grep operation running in a loop which is taking 1 minute to parse Whole SVN RedBook for finding concordance. I want that script to complete under 3 seconds, is that possible using Arrays or some other form?

Comment: Using `grep` *properly* is almost certainly going to be faster than anything you can cobble together in `bash`.

Comment: Use mapfile instead of a loop. It is *much* faster and no quoting is required. However, looping over a bash array will be an order of magnitude slower than just using grep.

Comment: I agree rici. I have to update BASH to 4.x

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After carefully thinking, it seems like I missed tr to replace the new line character and using eval (which is not that safe but it worked).

```
$ eval aaa=($(cat /tmp/ks.txt | sed "s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/" | tr '\012' ' '))
$ echo ${aaa[0]}
1 my name is koba
$
```